# OLD and NEW Pseudorecords for dynamic columns & Alternate

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle11g

AFAIK and what I saw in other answers, dynamic column check in trigger is not possible.

But it is worth to reconfirm and find alternatives as this will save lot of rework on every new column addition.
Scenario is : 
Table contains many columns and we need to write every update entry in other table. These updates can be on any column.

Is there any efficient way where we can avoid column name hardcoding in trigger ?

Comment: Not sure the issue with naming the columns in the trigger.  If you have a history table (with same structure as main table + a few date/flag fields), then changing the structure in the main table will simply require the same change to be applied to the history table and the trigger code.  Not a big deal imo, unless I'm missing some bigger problem?

Comment: History table contains below colulns :
1) column name 
2) New value 
3) old value 
4) change by 
5) change date time

So structure is different.

Comment: Ok, still don't see why changing the trigger when you alter the main table structure is a big problem though.  Perhaps you can post your trigger code.

Comment: found nearest solution on https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055
But not which I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We have used procedures to add/remove/change columns in a table, which also generated and compiled the trigger and CRUD procedures based on the table definition.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger should be considered part of the table and there should not be any abstraction between the trigger and table. I am a big fan of abstraction and use it whenever possible -- this is not one of those places.

If the underlying table should change in any way -- whether adding a column, dropping a column, or just renaming or retyping a column -- all triggers on the table should be rewritten as needed. They are of necessity too tightly coupled with the table to attempt otherwise.

In OO languages, the class is the basic unit of abstraction. The code within the class methods know the actual structure of the class and work with it as needed. If you make internal changes to the class, you rewrite the effected methods to abstract away any changes so the class user sees no difference (if possible). The method code is not abstracted precisely so the app code can be.

Triggers are like the methods of a class. They know all the dirty little secrets hidden in the class closet and work to keep those secrets hidden. They have to know every little detail of the closet and respond to all changes.

Look at it another way. The basic idea of SQL (and by extension the DBMS itself) is that the user asks for the data they want. The user does not specify the steps to take to obtain that data (it is declarative rather than procedural). The DBMS analyzes the request (declaration) and works out for itself the best way to get the data (procedure). The triggers are a part of that hidden process.

It is a design feature to help you deliver a scalable, responsive, adaptive product to your users, not a glitch to work around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
It is 2 step process with 2 triggers.
1st trigger is DDL trigger,which will trigger on DDL changes and will rewrite update trigger [step 2].

Materialized view logs are again replica of existing table, otherwise this can help a lot.